# Apply a process based on checklists and clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input box and a Parse button that when clicked applies a process to the data in the input box, and places the result in the Output box.

This input box also has several checkboxes that when ticked will require additional text processing to be done when the Parse button is clicked.

What is the best way of doing this? Do I need to set state for each checkbox and when the onClick event is clicked on the Parse button, it will check the current state for each checkbox? Or is there a better way of doing this?

[Input Box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpRPv.png)

Comment: A reproducible example would be great. It is time-consuming to reproduce from a mere image.

Comment: Storing the options in local state and conditionally performing their respective parsing operation is intuitive, and practically the best way to go here.